# `mod4 + m` no longer maximising client in awesome

Tags: awesome-wm

Other keys like `mod4 + j` and `mod4 + n` are working, but suddenly windows no longer maximise in `awesome`.

Restarting `awesome` did not fix it.

---

Here's what is probably the relevant line from `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua`:

```
 awful.key({ modkey,           }, "m",
        function (c)
            c.maximized_horizontal = not c.maximized_horizontal
            c.maximized_vertical   = not c.maximized_vertical
        end)
```

(I believe that's unmodified from the original.)

Answer (score 0):

Something else in the OS was conflicting with that key specifically. Once I `killall unity-2d-shell`ed the problem went away.